# Whats the use of this() in linkedlist.java

Tags: java, linked-list

Looking at Linkedlist.java, I observe overloaded constructors, one of which contains an empty this().
Generally I have seen this with default params. Whats the use of this() with no params in it ?

```
 /**
     * Constructs an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedList() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
     * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
     * iterator.
     *
     * @param  c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
     */
    public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        this();
        addAll(c);
    }
```

Comment: It's a call to the constructor with no parameters, no-op in this case.

Comment: It is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *constructor chaining*. It is the mechanism that enables objects to be initialized starting from the constructor of their most general superclass (`Object`) and moving down to the more specific ones (each level initializing the new object to a valid state for its class before moving on to the next).

A constructor can choose which other constructor of the current class (denoted by `this`) or the parent class (denoted by `super`) will be invoked before this one is run. The default chaining option is (implicitly) `super()`, unless something else is specified (or if a parameterless constructor in the parent class is not visible).

In your case, `this()` means that the constructor `LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)` will first call the `LinkedList()` constructor. While in your snippet it *is* a no-op, its presence ensures that any changes in the initialization strategy of the parameterless constructor will be also adopted by the other one. So it makes changing the initialization logic of the class a little less error prone.

Comment: Yes but whats the role of (this ()) in linkedlist.java ? It looks like a no-op

Comment: It's a provision for maintainability: in the future if some attributes are added, they may be initialized somewhere. The place to initialize them is the default constructor LinkedList(). By chaining today a no-op, we preserve the coherence of the class in the future.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper I just edited. It's  essentially what Aubin just said.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java language if you expose a constructor other than a default constructor the default constructor is disappearing. You may place the explicit default constructor. If the presence of the explicit default constructor is required along with non-default constructor `this()` should be placed in the constructor.